# Compilation error with delaunay mesher

Tags: mesh, cgal

I am trying to use the 2d meshing library for a code. I copied the syntax and the include files from the following example on the documentation

[mesh_global.cpp](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Mesh_2/Mesh_2_2mesh_global_8cpp-example.html)

But when I add the following line

```
CGAL::refine_Delaunay_mesh_2(cdt, Criteria(0.015625, sq3*a));
```

I get a compilation error pointing to the line

```
#include <CGAL/Delaunay_mesher_2.h>
```

The thing is the code compiles well without calling the meshing function.

The complete error is to big to post here but I found this line in between

```
/home/sameer/cgal/gap cvt/gap_cvt.cpp:1505:62:   required from here
/usr/include/CGAL/Delaunay_mesher_2.h:166:11: error: ‘class CGAL::Constrained_triangulation_face_base_2<CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_face_base_2<CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_ds_face_base_2<CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_2<CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_2<CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_ds_vertex_base_2<void> >, CGAL::Constrained_triangulation_face_base_2<CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_face_base_2<CGAL::Epick, CGAL::Triangulation_ds_face_base_2<void> > > > > > >’ has no member named ‘set_in_domain’
           it->set_in_domain(!mark);
```

I don't see what I am missing apart from the parameters the code has been taken almost as it is from the example.

Comment: are you sure you did not modify the triangulation type and in particular the face type?

Comment: I have only constructed the constrained delaunay triangulation upto that point by using cdt.insert(point_2) and cdt.insert_constraints(Point_2,Point_2).

Comment: could you post on gist or somewhere else `gap_cvt.cpp`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 2D mesher class [Delaunay_mesher_2](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Mesh_2/classCGAL_1_1Delaunay__mesher__2.html) expect the `CDT` template parameter to have a face type model of [DelaunayMeshFaceBase_2](http://doc.cgal.org/latest/Mesh_2/classDelaunayMeshFaceBase__2.html). You cannot use the default Triangulation data structure.

In the example you point out, the CDT type is declared as follow:

```
typedef CGAL::Exact_predicates_inexact_constructions_kernel K;
typedef CGAL::Triangulation_vertex_base_2<K> Vb;
typedef CGAL::Delaunay_mesh_face_base_2<K> Fb;
typedef CGAL::Triangulation_data_structure_2<Vb, Fb> Tds;
typedef CGAL::Constrained_Delaunay_triangulation_2<K, Tds> CDT;
```

Comment: Thanks that helped. I will take out the link now.